# Designing Database for my Android app

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, database-design

I have very limited experience using databases. I am designing [a game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tapdat&feature=search_result#?t=W10.) in which users enter location-based data which is then visually displayed to them. Similar to other apps which allow a user to share location-based data (i.e. restroom rating apps, etc), I would like to extend my app to allow users to view each other's data. I would like to know the best way to approach this problem. The following is how I assume that I should go about this:

I would start off by registering with a free hosting site (like 000webhost) until they become too slow for my needs. I would create a mysql database for the data. In the program, I would update the information with some sort of post request and retrieve it with a get request which would feed it into my data structures for viewing.

Does this seem like a reasonable plan of action or are there other ways to go about this process that would be more optimal? Like I said, I have very limited experience with databases so I am open to any tips/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is real simple, you might want to start with something like https://parse.com/. They're multi-platform, and have native sdks.

I think starting a from-scratch DB server with no prior knowledge will be a very large undertaking.

I'm sure there are other options, but this seems like a good candidate for Parse.

Comment: Thanks, they look promising! The only concern that I have is the api request limit.

Comment: After researching various BaaS's, I think that stackmob is the best choice.